# Docusign stop signed document to be sent to the signer

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way programmatically (using Java) to stop the signer from getting a notification and receiving the completed document?

I see an option in the user profile but I want to set it while sending an envelope.

Answer (score 0):

You could use embedded signing. That way DocuSign would not know the email address of the signer.

You should also check with your legal counsel about your plan. Asking someone to sign a document and then not giving them a copy of it is unusual behavior.